# Looking for an older anime floating crosses/people? Over earth

Tags: story-identification, anime, religion

I have this scene of an old anime stuck in my head and it’s bothering me I can’t find it. In the scene the main character looks up and sees floating crosses and light beams/ cloudy weather above earth, it zooms out and we see there are many many crosses. Really dark music plays in the background.

I think it’s the end of an old movie, it may be evongelion but when I look it up I can’t seem to pin point that image. This is also an old memory so maybe in my head it’s very skewed but thought I’d try here for a little help.

I want to say I saw this around 10 years ago but the anime itself was probably created in the 80s-90s range. (From what I saw of the art style, old animation style) what I remeber it was English and I believe there was a deep voice speaking over the music.

Comment: When did you see this? Any idea how old it was? What language was it in? *Any* extra details you can provide might help someone to find the answer! See also [our guidance on asking good ID questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394).

Comment: I want to say i saw this around 10 years ago but the anime itself was probably created in the 80s-90s range. (From what I saw of the art style, old animation style)  from what I remeber it was English and I believe there was a deep voice speaking over the music.

Comment: Maybe it was even the beginning of a movie but it seemed incredibly climactic / an important scene. I remeber feeling absolutely confused and terrified as a kid watching and really interested in finding it again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the end of '[The End of Evangelion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Evangelion)' where we see the results of the "third impact". In short, crosses appear everywhere, then various other weird stuff happens and keeps happening until the entire audience is completely baffled. Then it starts to get *downright obtuse*.

Comment: honestly it probably is, anywhere on youtube I can't find the scene I'm thinking of so I might just end up watching it through it really see. thank you

Comment: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/evangelion/images/9/91/Mari_with_the_Crosses_%28Rebuild%29.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20130225124944

Comment: oh ya definitely!

Comment: Third Impact, not fourth, right?

Comment: @David - I've lost track at this point. And anyone who claims that they haven't is a damned liar.

Comment: It was the [Third Impact](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Third_Impact) when the AT field, the stuff keep individuals (people) from merging (in a "cosmic conscience"), of all life forms on earth is tear apart by unit01 and Shinji chooses what kind of new world (apocalipse) we wants. I'm not a liar =)

Comment: @David What's confusing is that EoE is related to the original anime series. If you watched the series, the ending two episodes make little sense (it's mostly just Shinji and vague glimpses of what's happened). EoE was made as a "proper" end to the series, where you see the full acid trip in all its glory. But then there's the reboot movie series, which starts off mirroring the original series, but then diverges. The second movie ends with Third Impact, which is mysteriously interrupted. The third movie features a Fourth Impact.